# Does xsd2code uses xsd.exe or does it use its own code generation algorithm?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd.exe

Does xsd2code uses xsd.exe or does it use its own code generation logarithm?

- xsd2code can be found [here](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/)
- xsd.exe is the xsd generator tool from Microsoft

Comment: It's on CodePlex. Look at the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a brief browsing of the source code, it seems that xsd2code DOES NOT use the xsd tool. Both tools can read a schema file and generate serialization/deserialization code, but xsd2code seems more complete in what it can generates (listeners, observers, etc).